# C program to MPI parallel program

Tags: c

Hello i don't know if this is the right place to ask that. 
I have this MPI parallel Code that calculates PI and i need help understanding it for an oral exam.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(argc,argv)

int argc;

char *argv[];

{

    int done = 0, n, myid, numprocs, i;
    double PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643;
    double mypi, pi, h, sum, x;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    while (!done)
    {
    if (myid == 0) {
        printf("Enter the number of intervals: (0 quits) ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (n == 0) break;

    h   = 1.0 / (double) n;
    sum = 0.0;
    for (i = myid + 1; i <= n; i += numprocs) {
        x = h * ((double)i - 0.5);
        sum += 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x);
    }
    mypi = h * sum;

    MPI_Reduce(&mypi, &pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0,
           MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (myid == 0)
        printf("pi is approximately %.16f, Error is %.16f\n",
           pi, fabs(pi - PI25DT));
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which parts specifically - the MPI operations, or the calculation that approximates pi, or something else? (the K&R function parameters??)

Comment: hello thanks for replying
Mostly the calculation.I can understand the MPI operations

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. At first glance it looks like it's an integration, e.g. [the second one here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22785/71920) but over a positive range only. I'm not sure if that explains the x4 not the x2 though.

Comment: Yes, here's [the integral on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*+integrate+1%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)+from+0+to+1), which is at [the bottom of the question I linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076094/71920).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: okay thanks everyone for yours answers
They did help me so thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: [MPI](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/)

Starting from top:`MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);` is used to pass the command line arguments to all processes.

`MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);` returns the total number of MPI processes in the specified communicator (like MPI_COMM_WORLD) and their rank from pool.

`MPI_Bcast` Broadcasts (sends) a message from the process with rank "root" to all other processes in the group.(Here sending the number of iteration to every other process)

Between should be proper Monte Carlo pi estimation code.

And then the `MPI_Reduce` to Collect the areas calculated.

After that root prints the final pi value with error correction `PI25DT`.

Lastly `MPI_Finalize()` Terminates the MPI execution environment. This function should be the last MPI routine called in every MPI program - no other MPI routines may be called after it.

Pseudo for Monte Carlo Pi:

```
 for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

 x = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

 y = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

 z = x * x + y * y;

 if( z <= 1 ) count++;
 }

 pi = (double) count / n * 4;
```

Comment: "there is simple Monte Carli Pi estimation code" - no it isn't. Monte Carlo would be taking a random spot in a square and seeing if this falls within an inscribed circle, and there's no conditional code here.